# Making Youtube Stop Playing When Popover Is Dismissed, Or Using Javascript Youtube Controls

Tags: javascript, ipad, youtube, fullscreen, popover

So I've run into some problems implementing YouTube videos in popovers.  I can get the YouTube video to play just fine, but when the user clicks off the popover (destroying it), the sound continues playing.  My solution for this was to have the webview that was displaying the youtube video load a blank html string in the `viewDidDisappear` method, and this works great.

However, I am now running into an issue where if the user pushes the fullscreen button on the youtube video, the youtube video does indeed go fullscreen, but the popover is in front of it.  This is annoying, but the user could normally just click some other portion of the screen and it goes away.  I would be willing to live with this.  Except of course.....that calls `viewDidDisappear`, loading nothing into the html, blowing up my entire application.

I was wondering if anyone knew how to load some javascript in the webview that could control the youtube video.  In this way, I could have `viedDidDiappear` call the pause, so the sound would not continue playing when the popover is dismissed, and the youtube video would not blow up in full screen.

This is not the ideal solution (since the popover still sits in the way in full screen), but I will take it for now.  If anyone could help with the javascript injection I would need, or suggest an even better solution, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It's only on the iPad.  It's essentially a "popup" where you have a window on top of your main window.  It's pretty strictly controlled in its behavior.  All you can really do is tell it where to spawn, how big, and when to go away.

Comment: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/45726-ipad-how-find-out-when-youtube-player-plugin-goes-full-screen.html this link further illustrates my problems.  This person seems to have just given up :(